# Animation alignment

Tags: html, css, frontend

i am animating my modal to zoom and scale upon being called. i have set it to be aligned in the center yet the animation starts from right bottom corner of the screen and then moves to the center.[codepen for a better understanding](https://codepen.io/sanskarideadpool/pen/pobKYOB)

```
.animate {
-webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}
@keyframes animatezoom {
from {transform: scale(0)} 
to {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `top`, `left`, `position` and `transform` properties from the `login-modal-content` class and change the `margin: auto`. So your `login-modal-content` css looks like this:

```
.login-modal-content {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    text-align: center;
    border:none;
    background: #3e3e3f;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color:#ffff;
    width: 35%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    margin: auto;
}
```

You already position the parent to be center, so it is not necessary to position the child as `absolute` as well. It is relative to its parent.